# React JS - Map Function - Accessing Local Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, map-function

I have a Dropdown and Search Box (based on the dropdown menu, the searchbox fetches results from respective JSON files)

```
function onSearch({ currentTarget }) {
 var i = document.getElementById("SearchBox")  
 if (i.value == 1) {
  const results = fuse.search(query);
  const RequestResults = results ? results.map(data => data.item) : global;
  const srResults = RequestResults.slice(0, limit)
  console.table(srResults)
  updateQuery(currentTarget.value);
 }
 else if (i.value == 2) {
  const eucresults = eucfuse.search(query);
  const RequestResults = eucresults ? eucresults.map(data => data.item) : euc;
  const srResults = RequestResults.slice(0, limit)
  console.table(srResults)
  updateQuery(currentTarget.value);
 }
}
```

When I try to fetch the results in a component, I get srResults as undefined as they are local.

```
{srResults.map(data => {
const { name, link } = data;
return (
<p ><small>{name}</small></p>
)
})}
```

I am new to React and can anyone help me in fixing this. I have tried using Jquery.append and I dont want use it.

Comment: Did not get why you need jquery or smth while you're using react, take a look at a tutorial here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-simple-dynamic-search-bar-in-react-js-f1659d64dfae

Comment: Just tried with jQuery to see the results. The current app is built on jQ and bootstrap 3 and we are migrating to react and thanks for the link :-)

Comment: Yeah, don't manipulate the DOM directly in React as that can cause weird issues.
What is the ```query``` variable in this ```const results = fuse.search(query);```

Comment: Capturing the text that the user inputs
 <Search id="SearchBox" value={query} onChange={onSearch} />